# How to get inline-blocks to sit side-by-side?

Tags: html, css

[code pen](http://codepen.io/mnbayazit/pen/KpeJo)

## html

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td id="meow">

      <div id="a"><input type="radio"><input type="radio"></div>
        <div id="b">some text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

## css

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#meow {
  width: 300px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#a {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#b {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

How do I get `#b` to sit to the right of `#a`? I don't want the text to wrap below `#a` which is why I'm using an [inline] block-level element. `float: left` doesn't seem to work either.

I do not want to fix the size of `#b`.

Comment: If you already created a layout based on `table` , why dont you continue down that path ?

Comment: Please see my answer - I hope this works for you :)

Comment: I don't get why but if you take the width of off `#meow` it works pretty much as expected.

Comment: @Slytherin: I certainly could, but I'm trying not to encourage bad behaviour. The table is from an old layout. I'm trying to teach my co-workers that all this stuff can be done with CSS, but I'm failing :\

Comment: @Will If you take the width off `#meow` then `#b` has enough room to stretch out, unless your browser window is too small, which is the scenario I was trying to force for the demo by giving it a width.

Comment: I have a solution for you, please see my edited answer :)

Comment: @Notulysses System blew up. Will come back to this tomorrow. Your solution looks the best :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can apply `display:table-cell` to the `#a` and `#b` and `white-space:nowrap` to force `#a` not to wrap inner `<input>`s in a column but display them in one row.

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CDwvh)

Answer (score 0):

You can set display block in the #b and set a  margin left

http://jsfiddle.net/bN9FR/

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td id="meow">

           <div id="a"><input type="radio"><input type="radio"></div><div id="b">some text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#meow {
  width: 300px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#a {
  background-color: yellow;
    float:left;

}

#b {
  background-color: orange;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 50px;

}
```

Comment: You've essentially fixed the size of `#a` to a max of 50px. That's not going to work for me, unfortunately.